# Can't type ^ in xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

I need ^ to evaluate expressions with powers, such as x^2. However, it does not appear if I try to type it. I don't know if it is related, but my keyboard is pt_BR although I've set Ubuntu in English.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to copy the ^ symbol and paste it in xmgrace with the shift+insert combination.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout#/media/File:KB_Portuguese.svg), the ^ symbol on a Portugese keyboad is over by the return key. 
On an English keyboard it is `Shift+6`. If you have changed the keyboard language to English then please try this.

Alternatively you can try to copy and paste, as suggested in the comments.